# Why are css animations faster on a mobile device?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I got this question because i faced this problem many times and the only thing i can think off is the "hardware acceleration" of mobile devices is different than the one of a computer based browser.

The problem what i'm talking about is that if you make a animation of css, the time you put in as seconds shows different on mobile devices.(its like 10x faster.)

If you make a class or id with the line:

```
-webkit-animation:keyFrameName 10s infinite;
```

It wil be on mobile device like 1s and on laptop 10s.

Any one knows a solution to sync the time of a laptop browser and device browser?

All things are welcome, it's just a question that might change some things for the developer world.

---

Edit 1:
The keyframes are like this:

```
@-webkit-keyframes RAani{
0%{opacity:1.0;}
50%{opacity:0.25;}
100%{opacity:1.0;}
}
@-moz-keyframes RAani{
0%{opacity:1.0;}
50%{opacity:0.25;}
100%{opacity:1.0;}
}
@keyframes RAani{
0%{opacity:1.0;}
50%{opacity:0.25;}
100%{opacity:1.0;}
}
```

Comment: I'm sure a lot of this comes down to the mobile OS - what OS are you referring to?

Comment: Windows for laptop, and for mobile on android and IOS.

Comment: Also, some animation effects depends on the browsers which you are using...

Comment: Define "mobile device" and "laptop browser" - what are those?

Comment: Laptop runs on 64 bit windows 8.1 and my Iphone 5 runs on IOS 8.1 i don't know what android version my neighbour uses

Comment: Using chrome as browser also safari and IE

Comment: I'm guessing they are faster because there are less pixels to cover? Anyone second this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
-webkit-animation: keyFrameName 10s infinite;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
-moz-animation: keyFrameName 10s infinite;
-moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
-o-animation: keyFrameName 10s infinite;
-o-animation-timing-function: linear;
animation: keyFrameName 10s infinite;
animation-timing-function: linear;
```

Comment: Works on IOS! When i get home ill test on android but for now i got the best anwser! Thanks!!!

Comment: Problem keeps showing up, device is faster as laptop

Comment: On which devices have you tried it? Can you post your keyframes part of your css script?

Comment: I'll add it to the question as edit. (Added) also i tried it this time on iphone ipad (both IOS 8.1) and windows 8.1 chrome , safari and IE.

Comment: Also i don't think its a code error but a configuration of the app, on the ipad it just does as windows its like 10s and on my iphone it's still 1s instead of 10s.

Comment: I created this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6czncdjo/ . I tried it on safari (IOS 8.4.1, IOS 9 and OSX El Capitan), on Chrome and microsoft Edge. Works well for me.

Comment: After doing a restore on my iphone it seems to be fixed, i don't know what caused this problem...